# using stickytableheaders with requirejs not loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I am trying to load [stickytableheaders](https://github.com/jmosbech/StickyTableHeaders) with requirejs and can't seem to get it to work. Always says that it's not found. I have confirmed it's loading that script prior to the use of it.

any idea why `$("table").stickyTableHeaders();` would throw an `undefined is not a function` error?

Config file

```
var require = {
    baseUrl: "/",
    paths: {
        "bootstrap": "Scripts/bootstrap/bootstrap",
        "jquery": "Scripts/jquery/jquery-1.9.1",        
        "stickyTableHeaders": "Scripts/stickyheader/stickyheader",
        "knockout": "Scripts/knockout/knockout-3.3.0",
        "text": "Scripts/require/text",
        "domReady": "Scripts/require/domReady"
    },
    shim: {
        "bootstrap": {
            deps: ["jquery"]
        },
        'stickyTableHeaders': {
            deps: ['jquery'],
            exports: 'jQuery.fn.stickyTableHeaders'
        }
    }
}
```

startup file

```
require(['jquery'
    , 'knockout'
    , 'Scripts/App/components/appViewModel'
    , 'stickyTableHeaders'
    , 'bootstrap'
    , '/Scripts/knockout/bindinghandlers.js'
    , 'domReady!']
    , function ($, ko, appViewModel, stickyTableHeaders) {

    ko.components.register('reportingline', { require: 'Scripts/App/components/reportingline/line' });
    ko.components.register('newrpt', { require: 'Scripts/App/components/newrpt/newreport' });

    $("table").stickyTableHeaders();

    ko.applyBindings(new appViewModel());
})
```

Comment: First thing I see is that all your paths start with `Scripts` except for the one in question, which uses `/Scripts`. Could it just be a simple typo?

Comment: unfortunately not.  I'll correct that typo, but I show that file loading in the page before it's being used.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to get it to work.

I had to add the code to the end of the view model for the page that it was needed on.  Seems there should be a way to do it globally though.

$("table").stickyTableHeaders();